# Detailed info about server's hardware on esxi

Tags: hard-drive, esxi, hp-proliant

I have HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 and on it VMware ESXI. I want to find out detailed info about the device, specially about harddisk bay and connectors, so to be sure if i can add extra harddisk expansion bay. I browsed HP ILO, remote console, vSphere Client but i can't get needed info. How do i get detailed hardware info without opening the device?

Comment: On my server, all the information, is in HP ILO

Comment: i do use ILO to, but i can't get detailed info, I need to find out if i can add extra SFF 8-drive cage. It has extra place for cage. it seems to have. But as i have already tried to find connectors and measure the place, i accidentally powered off the production server. So i'm afraid to touch it again )) So before ordering i need to be sure.

Comment: HP ILO isn't going to report on something that isn't connected to it.  It will simply indicate that location is blank, since nothing is reporting its status, best just open it up.

Comment: Read the manual for the server and have a look at what's already being reported to be in there to compare that information. Otherwise open it up and have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information will be found in the documentation for the server, not on the server itself.

If you do not have the original configuration for the server handy, you should be able to plug the serial number into the HP support site to find the original config, and then by looking at the capabilities for that model, you should be able to determine what capabilities can be added with extra hardware.

This is the standard way of determining the upgrade capability of a server.

There will not be a place in the server itself that will say "Hi, I can accept an Acme Drive Tray and a Widget Connectorinator here".